# How to prepare Vue component-based project with routing, based on existing resources?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, routes, loader

I'm quite new in Vue, so maybe it would be an obvious question for you.

I'm working on Java web application in microservices architecture and I've decided to prepare frontend part of all my services in Vue. My frontend views schould look very similar because this will be a CRM type of app. I already prepared my HTML skeleton, CSS styles and JS using Pingendo.

What is important I need to keep my Header and Footer sections the same all the time in specified microservice. Best option for such thing is to use routing in Vue and rout only the content between Header and Footer components. Generally rather obvious idea.

**The problem is how to create new Vue project using already prepared HTML, CSS and JS files?**

I used Vue CLI to create my project and just run `vue create project-name` command with default configuration.

Pingendo use Bootstrap, JQuery and Popper libraries, which I have to import to my Vue project using `npm 
install bootstrap jquery popper.js` to install it and I have no warnings and errors now coused by lack of dependecies to this libraries.

I have also follow [this instructions](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup) and installed basic config of webpack using `npm install -D vue-loader vue-template-compiler` but after `npm run serve` I have an error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                         10:10:28 PM

 error  in ./src/components/test

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#
loaders
> <template>
|     <h2>this is TEST Component content</h2>
| </template>

 @ ./src/router/index.js 4:0-37 14:15-19
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.7:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

My Test.vue component is very simple:

```
<template>
    <h2>this is TEST Component content</h2>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'test'
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Everything has a default config with necessary additions. What steps should I do to make such project working?

Repository: https://bitbucket.org/jacekmucha91/storycrm-manager-vue/src/master/

Answer (score 0):

It is questionable using jQuery with Vue. You can do the things you need to in Vue without jQuery, so I would first check that you are correctly choosing the tools you need. What exactly do you need jQuery for that Vue won't handle?

Additionally, there are a lot of plugins for Vue that handle the nuances properly, so for Bootstrap you should be installing `Bootstrap-Vue` as well. Check that there aren't specific-to-Vue versions of libraries you want to use. This will let you avoid these issues.

For reference:
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: thank you for suggestion :) I've done many tries during the day, and finally  after configure new project with Webpack following [this instructions](https://dev.to/macmacky/how-to-configure-webpack-and-vue-from-the-ground-up-4c19), configure routing again using [this instructions](https://appdividend.com/2018/12/28/vue-router-tutorial-with-example-how-to-use-routing-in-vuejs/) and [import BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/) project is working, but I see not the same classes like in my base project created in Pingendo.

Comment: Pingendo suggests me, that I have to include this files: > https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js > https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js > https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js